Micronaut application in AWS Lambda throwing jwks Bean error
I have a Micronaut Kotlin application that I'm trying to host in AWS Lambda. I have the Lambda setup as a proxy behind AWS API Gateway. The code works perfectly locally and I can call the APIs using the JWKS from our IDP with this config.
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: video-translation-api
  serde:
    maximum-nesting-depth: 2000
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          jwks:
            auth0:
              url: ${JWT_SIGNATURE}


datasources:
  default:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    dialect: POSTGRES
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME:""}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD:""}
    url: ${DATABASE_URL:""}

---
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        bytecode:
          provider: none
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: validate
        show_sql: false

`
However, when I deploy the jar to Lambda I get the following error.
Bean definition [io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.HttpClientJwksClient] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for parameter [clientRegistry] of class: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.HttpClientJwksClient

Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry<io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient>] exists. 
* [HttpClientRegistry<HttpClient>] is disabled because it is within the package [io.micronaut.http.client] which is disabled due to bean requirements: 
 - No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry] present within context
Path Taken: new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry,HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration) --> new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,[HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry],HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration): io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.HttpClientJwksClient] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for parameter [clientRegistry] of class: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.HttpClientJwksClient

Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry<io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient>] exists. 
* [HttpClientRegistry<HttpClient>] is disabled because it is within the package [io.micronaut.http.client] which is disabled due to bean requirements: 
 - No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry] present within context
Path Taken: new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry,HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration) --> new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,[HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry],HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:2003)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3384)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3739)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:363)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:202)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.startEnvironment(AbstractExecutor.java:124)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.FunctionInitializer.startThis(FunctionInitializer.java:124)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.FunctionInitializer.<init>(FunctionInitializer.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.payload1.ApiGatewayProxyRequestEventFunction.<init>(ApiGatewayProxyRequestEventFunction.java:38)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler.<init>(MicronautLambdaHandler.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [clientRegistry] of class: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.HttpClientJwksClient

Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry<io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient>] exists. 
* [HttpClientRegistry<HttpClient>] is disabled because it is within the package [io.micronaut.http.client] which is disabled due to bean requirements: 
 - No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry] present within context
Path Taken: new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry,HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration) --> new HttpClientJwksClient(BeanContext beanContext,[HttpClientRegistry clientRegistry],HttpClientConfiguration defaultClientConfiguration)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2181)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1328)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.$HttpClientJwksClient$Definition.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2332)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2302)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2314)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3116)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3018)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeEagerBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2699)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1997)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry<io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient>] exists. 
* [HttpClientRegistry<HttpClient>] is disabled because it is within the package [io.micronaut.http.client] which is disabled due to bean requirements: 
 - No bean of type [io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientRegistry] present within context
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultBeanContext.java:2789)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultApplicationContext.java:309)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2758)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1752)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2165)
    ... 25 more

When I disable security: enabled: true the code runs as expected so I'm 100% sure it's to do with how Micronaut is handling JWKS.
I've also tried loading the JWKS directly into Micronaut through Env var for testing. I've also tried opening up the Lambda to see if it was a connection issue but I still get the same error.
I've not been able to find anything to point me in the correct direction as to what could be causing this error.
Thanks in advance.

I had a similar issue. For me, I had a Gradle dependency that was compile-time only:
compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
I resolved this issue by changing it to an implementation dependency:
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
